# Скрипт до якоря крутит с багом

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть скрипт для плавной прокрутки до якоря, но после выполнения на 0.2 мс появляется какой-то скачек на экране, после этого он крутит до якоря.

В чем может быть проблема?

```js
$(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= "250") 
    $("#ToTop").fadeIn("slow")
    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() <= "250") 
      $("#ToTop").fadeOut("slow")
    else 
      $("#ToTop").fadeIn("slow")
  });

  if ($(window).scrollTop() <= $(document).height() - "") 
    $("#rentacar").fadeIn("slow")
    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - "") 
      $("#rentacar").fadeOut("slow")
    else 
      $("#rentacar").fadeIn("slow")
  });

  $("#ToTop").click(function() {
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow")
  })
  
  $("#rentacar").click(function() {
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: 1500
    }, "slow")
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот держи:

```
$(function() {
    function top() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() <= "250")
            $("#ToTop").fadeOut("slow")
        else
            $("#ToTop").fadeIn("slow")
    }
    top()

    function scr() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - "")
            $("#rentacar").fadeOut("slow")
        else
            $("#rentacar").fadeIn("slow")
    }
    scr()
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        top()
        scr()
    });

    $("#ToTop").on('click', function() {
        $("body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500, "linear")
        return false;
    })

    $("#rentacar").click(function() {
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: 1500
        }, "slow")
        return false;
    })
});
```